# What is the best way to create a file in WEH 8.1 that's accessible from pc windows explorer via usb connection

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I have a Windows Mobile 6.5 app which doesn't have any restrictions. I generate the file and put it on the cradle, connect to pc, and can copy from Windows Explorer.

I need to be able to do the same in Windows Phone 8.1, generate a text or csv file that should be accessible on any folders, preferably Documents folder, which can be copied over to pc via Windows Explorer.

I have been trying different ways, but none of them works.

Folder Picker: (throwing Not Supported error)

```
Windows.Storage.Pickers.FolderPicker picker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FolderPicker();
picker.SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.Downloads;
StorageFolder folder = await picker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
```

External storage: (Access denied error)

```
StorageFolder externalDevices = Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.RemovableDevices;
StorageFolder sdCard = (await externalDevices.GetFoldersAsync()).FirstOrDefault();
```

Documents: (Access denied error)

```
StorageFolder folder = KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work, at least on the MusicLibrary folder.

> First, go to Project Properties -> Application -> Package Manifest ->
>   Capabilities (tab) -> check Music Library

```
public static async Task<bool> WriteFile(string data)
{
        StorageFolder mfolder = KnownFolders.MusicLibrary;
        StorageFolder folder = await mfolder.CreateFolderAsync("MyFolder", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
        StorageFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync("log.txt", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        await Windows.Storage.FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file, data);
        return true;
}
```